# DB2 Select where not equal to string that is NULL

Tags: sql, db2

I have `COLUMN1 CHAR(1)` in `MYTABLE` where all rows are `NULL` and here is my sql query:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM MYTABLE WHERE COLUMN1 != 'A'
```

it returns nothing because all rows have `NULL` in `COLUMN1`. I suppose it should return everything. How do I make it work? I don't wanna use

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(COLUMN1, ''), '*')
```

because it slows down the query. Is there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want NULLs, then why not

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM MYTABLE WHERE (COLUMN1 != 'A' OR COLUMN1 IS NULL)
```

???

Answer (score 3):

Your supposition is wrong.  Basically all comparison operators with `NULL` return "false" or `NULL` (which are both filtered out in a `WHERE` clause), except for `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

So, your query should be:

```
WHERE column1 <> 'A' OR COLUMN1 IS NULL
```

Or, alternatively, use `COALESCE()` (NOT `NULLIF()`:

```
WHERE COALESCE(column1, '') <> 'A'
```

Answer (score 3):

Think to the semantic of `NULL`. You can use it the way you want, but it is meant to mean "unknown". Unknown = 'A'? Nope. But unknown != 'A'? Nope. We simply don't know what it is, so almost all comparisons will fail.

You can use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`, two special operators designed to work with `NULL`. So you can do something like:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM MYTABLE WHERE COLUMN1 != 'A' OR COLUMN1 IS NULL
```

But first ask yourself: is this what you want? Are you really using `NULL` for unknown values? SQL semantics for `NULL` is perfectly logical if you consider it an unknown value, but it complicates everything unnecessarily in all other cases. Basically, introducing `NULL` in SQL was probably a mistake, because the problems it causes in 1 day are more than the problems it solved in the relational theory's history until now.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem comparing VARCHAR and NULL values and solved used COALESCE(), in your case you can do something

```
WHERE COALESCE(column1,'') != 'A'
```

Comment: How is this any different from the last part of [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36501537/10871073), posted nearly 8 years ago>